# Python 2.7 pandas to fill missing number/series

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Here is a shorten table.

```
ID,NUMBER,DEVICE
A,103,L
A,104,L
B,101,L
B,102,D
C,101,V
C,102,V
C,103,L
C,104,L
```

The goal here is to output the "DEVICE" pattern for each unique "ID". There should be in total 4 number: 101,102,103,104 in the "Number" column.  If any "NUMBER" column is missing, we fill in "N" in the "DEVICE" column. For example, number 101 and 102 are missing in the "A" ID, so we wanna fill in the following fashion:

```
ID,NUMBER,DEVICE
A,101,N
A,102,N
A,103,L
A,104,L
```

The goal here is to output the "DEVICE" pattern for each unique "ID". Therefore, by filling the necessary "N" in the "DEVICE" column, we are hoping to get outputs like this by using "groupby":

{"A,NNLL","B,LDNN","C,VVLL"}

Could any guru help regarding the first missing value filling?  Python Pandas way is more welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one liner (actually eight lines, but broken for readability).  The output of what you requested is not valid: it is neither a list nor a dictionary.  I have exported the contents as a dictionary, but could do a list format if you prefer.

```
>>> {key: "".join(value) 
     for key, value in 
     df
     .pivot(index='ID', columns='NUMBER', values='DEVICE')
     .fillna('N')
     .T
     .to_dict('list')
     .iteritems()}
{'A': 'NNLL', 'B': 'LDNN', 'C': 'VVLL'}
```

The main part of the solution is the pivot table, where we fill missing values with `N`.

```
>>> df.pivot(index='ID', columns='NUMBER', values='DEVICE').fillna('N')
NUMBER 101 102 103 104
ID                    
A        N   N   L   L
B        L   D   N   N
C        V   V   L   L
```

This basically gets the data we want, now we just have to restructure it.  If we call the output above `df2`, then:

```
result_dict = df2.T.to_dict('list')
>>> result_dict
{'A': ['N', 'N', 'L', 'L'],
 'B': ['L', 'D', 'N', 'N'],
 'C': ['V', 'V', 'L', 'L']}
```

This, in turn, can be joined together using a dictionary comprehension:

```
result_dict2 = {key: "".join(value) for key, value in result_dict.iteritems()}
>>> result_dict2
{'A': 'NNLL', 'B': 'LDNN', 'C': 'VVLL'}
```

Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension:

```
result3 = [key + ", " + "".join(value) for key, value in result_dict.iteritems()]
>>> result3
['A, NNLL', 'C, VVLL', 'B, LDNN']
```

Comment: oh my budda, this is dirty!

Comment: What's dirty about it?  It is just a condensed version of the longer explanation.

Comment: Meaning it is a very clean solution!

Comment: I REALLY like this pivot table solution. Elegant and FAST!